# Place div directly above parent div

Tags: html, css

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/S2Kaw/454/

Notice that the child div is slightly offset. Ive found answers where you can add top to the css like so :

```
top:-20px;
```

But I don't want to set this myself. What is the best way so it doesn't have any margin/padding etc. I have tried :

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

But no luck

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question title - do you want to put the child div immediately above its parent, or have the child div sit snuggly inside its parent?

Comment: placing div above parent and zero padding are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set padding top to zero in `.container-div`

http://jsfiddle.net/S2Kaw/455/

```
.container-div {
  padding: 0px 10px 0;
  background-color:#c3c3c3;
  width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you essentially need to do is give `padding:0px` to your `container-div`.